# Regex to replace all characters except for values in brackets

Tags: regex

I have this data:

> [1265]*[1263]jklasdjklfasjdf[2234]

I am trying to trim all characters except for the brackets with values in them.

I.e result should be [1265][1263][2234]

Answer (score 0):

Your language is not regular, and you should build a parser for this instead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages